# Can a person be charged in absentia in the English and Welsh jurisdiction?

Tags: england-and-wales, process

In England and Wales a person can certainly be tried in absentia, but can they be charged in absentia?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know the answer in this jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer is yes. They can be reported for summons and then sent a summons to attend the Magistrates Court by post.